# how do I resolve 'not all code paths return data'?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
   private DataSet getData(HiddenField sDate, HiddenField eDate)
{

    jQueryUICalendar1.Text = sDate.Value;
    jQueryUICalendar2.Text = eDate.Value;

}
```

```html
<label>Report Start Date:&nbsp;<asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Visible="true" id="sDate"  Value="" /><asp:TextBox runat="server" inputtype="Date" size="25" value="Click to select start date..."  ID="jQueryUICalendar1" ControlID="jQueryUICalendar1" TextMode="SingleLine" MaxLength="10" Rows="1" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox></label>
        &nbsp;<label>Report End Date:&nbsp;<asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Visible="true"  id="eDate" Value=""  /><asp:TextBox runat="server" inputtype="Date" size="25" value="Click to select end date..." ID="jQueryUICalendar2" ControlID="jQueryUICalendar2" TextMode="SingleLine" MaxLength="10" Rows="1" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox></label>
```

I'm trying to figure out why 'getData' returns no value from the HiddenField.  What do I need to do to my c0de to have getData return the appropriate value (e.g.,  jQueryUICalendar1, jQueryUICalendar2)

Comment: _private void getData_  in your code you say that you want to return a DataSet from getData, but there is no return value from that function so you declare the it returns _void_

Comment: Before someone asks,  the page in question (*.aspx, *.aspx.cs) contains a Form with TWO textboxes (e.g.,  startDate, endDate).  When the user selects a startDate (textbox1) & endDate (textbox2) those values need to go into the HiddenField you see in my code (above) so that they may be passed as variables to MySQL.

Comment: @Steve --- says "Field cannot have void type."

Comment: @Steve --  if I do:

private void getData, then VS accepts code.   Still don't know if it works yet though xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not returning a `DataSet`, set your method return to `void`

```
private void getData(HiddenField sDate, HiddenField eDate)  // <  -- return void
{
    jQueryUICalendar1.Text = sDate.Value;
    jQueryUICalendar2.Text = eDate.Value;
}
```

Either that, or just return a `DataSet`

```
private DataSet getData(HiddenField sDate, HiddenField eDate)
{
    jQueryUICalendar1.Text = sDate.Value;
    jQueryUICalendar2.Text = eDate.Value;

    DataSet myReturn = new DataSet();
    // Do things with myReturn
    return myReturn;
}
```

Comment: ---  your help is most appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you've declared a return type of 'DataSet', but your function does not return a value. Either change the return type to void (which means no return type) or have your function return the correct type/value.

Comment: perhaps I failed to mention I'm a C# noob?   -HOW- do I get the correct type/value?

Comment: @Cryptik `perhaps I failed to mention I'm a C# noob?` And you try to write code without knowing the basic things. I would read some docs before continueing....

Comment: @Eser -- I've read docs.  I'll continue to read docs, however, as someone with less than >2months of experience working with C#, I thought I'd inquire with more experienced minds on the matter.

Comment: I must agree some research/reading would be best. Understanding core data types of a language is fundamental in using the language. At least being able to find the resources to learn about them: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx] Do you actually want anything returned from this function or is the goal to do 'something'?

Comment: @William_Wilson --   ("do you actually want anything returned from this function or is the goal to do 'something'?")     What I -want- this function to do is take the values (start & end dates) that the user selects using the jQueryUICalendar and have those date ranges displayed in the GridView that I've constructed.